# How can i generate a report using reportLab and Python Object

Tags: python, reporting, reportlab

I'm trying to generate a PDF report using python Object and reportLab , i did not find a simple example for this , also the documentation is not clear.

For example i have this python class

```
class Article ():
    _designation=None
    _type=None
```

I want to show for example many Article Object in a [blockTable](https://www.reportlab.com/software/rml-reference/) , how can i resolve it ?

Comment: I don't know if you really want to use the RML interface to reportlab. If this is your first time with reportlab, i would suggest that you take a look at this [example](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/platypus-example.py), which illutrates the normal approach to dynamic pdf generation (platypus). If something is unclear, have look at the user guide, which is located [here](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf). The platypus chapter is the interesing one.

Comment: thanks , i'm trying to understand it , if some thing is wrong  i will add comment